# How to Load Data From a Json Using Thymeleaf Template

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a rest api returns a Json value as a Output of the service call.

eg:- `https://localhost:8080/getEmployees/loadAll`

this returns following json values
eg:-

```
{
"employees":[
  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
}
```

I need to load the following json values to my thymeleaf table. 
In normal way returning values in controller using modal in spring can retun values as list like following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee List</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 <br>
 <h3>Employee List</h3>
 <br />
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>Employee First Name</td>
   <td>Employee Last Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each="emp : ${empList}">
   <td th:text="${emp.firstName}">First Name</td>
   <td th:text="${emp.name}">Last Name</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

is there a way to accomplish this using above json using thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are a little confused. Thymeleaf templates are compiled on server side generating html code. Then, no thymeleaf code found on client side.

The json data got of the api response is generated on client side.

One way is use javascript to load the api response data into a html table.

Another way can you take is modify the controller that calls to the thymeleaf template to get the JSon value. If you store this response (on an object List named empList on your example) yo can add the object into the Controller response (Model or ModelAndView objects) as a template attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. so that you are saying if i want to load the json data to table using java-script request get the data and generate HTML table dynamically using java-script right?

Comment: Exactly. You could use a datatable (https://datatables.net/) to print a table. It's easiest to load data than a html table.

Comment: I'm using my own template for that. Thank you so much for the info i will try datatables.net.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like that using the following structure.

When you call the service

`https://localhost:8080/getEmployees/loadAll`

you will need to pass the employees data using model.addAttribute.

For instance, let's say you have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getEmployees/loadAll")
String getAllEmployees(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("empList", <your service here that generates the data>);
    return "pagenamehere";
}
```

The above method, will only be executed when you make a call using the following url: `https://localhost:8080/getEmployees/loadAll`
and it will add your `empList` data as an attribute. Then, the return string indicates the name of the page that will load. You will need to use your own page with the thymeleaf code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee List</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 <br>
 <h3>Employee List</h3>
 <br />
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>Employee First Name</td>
   <td>Employee Last Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each="emp : ${empList}">
   <td th:text="${emp.firstName}">First Name</td>
   <td th:text="${emp.lastNname}">Last Name</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, thymeleaf will be able to display the given data.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer When adding to model attribute i'm calling my service https://localhost:8080/getEmployees/loadAll from there right ?
so do i have to get that json values and create a arraylist to pass tothe thymeleaf?

Comment: Exactly, you will need to call your service to get your JSON values, pass them into an ArrayList and then pass that array list to the thymeleaf using the model attribute.